# Multiple "wvdpforce" parameter in access log. Where it comes from

Tags: apache, logging, webserver

In our apache access log, we found a lot of url ending with the parameter 'wvdpforce=1'

Anyone knows where this parameter come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JF Paris, I've encountered this problem too (it seems centered around France and began around February according to my research). From my logs, the behavior looks like some sort of browser hijack, not an injection bot. From what I could witness it doesn't seem harmful (no injection attempts in URL/POST) but I'd be very interested to have a definitive answer as well.

Comment: Thank you, I will continue to monitor it. If I found something, I will advise.

Comment: I have been facing this too. 

In my case, I get a duplicate HTTP request with all the parameters + wvdpforce in the 2nd request. It happens for all requests coming from particular user_agent + IP, leading me to believe that is indeed some sort of browser hijack.